# keras sequential().predict(x_test) only returns 1 column for two classes

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, sequential

I'm having problem with keras `sequential().predict(x_test)`.

Btw getting the same output using `sequential().predict_proba(x_test)` as I found that these two are indifferent in sequential now.

My data has two classes: 0 or 1, I believe `predict(x_test)` should give two columns, where the first column is the prob for getting 0 and the second is prob of getting 1. However I only have one column with this.

```
    In [85]:y_train.value_counts()
    Out[85]: 
    0    616751
    1     11140
    Name: _merge, dtype: int64
```

There should be no problem with my data as I used the same x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test for both LogisticRegression model and neural network model, it works perfect in LogisticRegression.

```
In [87]:y_pred_LR
Out[87]: 
array([[  9.96117151e-01,   3.88284921e-03],
       [  9.99767583e-01,   2.32417329e-04],
       [  9.87375774e-01,   1.26242258e-02],
       ..., 
       [  9.72159138e-01,   2.78408623e-02],
       [  9.97232916e-01,   2.76708432e-03],
       [  9.98146985e-01,   1.85301489e-03]])
```

but I only get 1 column in neural network model.

So I guess there is some problem with the NN model setting up? Here is my codes

```
NN = Sequential()
NN.add(Dense(40, input_dim = 65, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
NN.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
NN.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
NN.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

NN.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size = 50, epochs=5)
y_pred_NN = NN.predict(x_test)
print(y_pred_NN)

    In [86]: print(y_pred_NN)
    [[ 0.00157279]
     [ 0.0010451 ]
     [ 0.03178826]
     ..., 
     [ 0.01030775]
     [ 0.00584918]
     [ 0.00186538]]
```

Actually it looks like it's the prob of getting 1? 
Any help is appreciated!

Btw the shapes of my predictions in both models are as follows

```
In [91]:y_pred_LR.shape
Out[91]: (300000, 2)

In [90]:y_pred_NN.shape
Out[90]: (300000, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output two probabilities, you will have to replace your `y_train` with `to_categorical(y_train)` and then adjust the network accordingly:

```
from keras.utils import to_categorical

NN = Sequential()
NN.add(Dense(40, input_dim = 65, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
NN.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'relu'))
NN.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
NN.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])

NN.fit(x_train, to_categorical(y_train), batch_size = 50, epochs=5)
```

Consult here: https://keras.io/utils/#to_categorical

Comment: If that's the case, what is the shape of y_pred_NN and of y_train?

Comment: y_pred_NN.shape=(300000,1) ;  y_train.shape=(627891,)

Comment: I tested my updted answer on a similar problem, it works - try it.

Answer (score 1):

The last line of your model defines the output layer.

```
NN.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'sigmoid'))
```

Your last line has one node, with a sigmoid activation. This means that your output will be a single number (per input sample) between 0 and 1, which I believe you can interpret as P(y=1), as per logistic regression.

With more than two classes you would have `n_classes` in the output layer:

```
NN.add(Dense(n_classes, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', activation = 'softmax'))
```

The softmax ensures that the probabilities sum to unity. Of course to do this you would have to one-hot encode your training y values.

In your case you can choose between either approach. I favour the second, as it allows you to add more classes in the future.

Comment: So basically it's just prob(y=1) here, and if I wanna know p(y=0) it would be 1 minus the column that I get... thank you! :)